# Dynamically Running VBA code when sheet changes

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way in which I can get a sub in VBA to run whenever the user changes the sheet. Basically, what I am looking to do is hide all of the sheets besides the one that the user is on.

Thanks!

Comment: If all sheets are hidden besides the one that the user is on then how would user navigate to other sheets?

Comment: @DavidZemens Yes, does make sense.

Comment: @Santosh I've seen that approach done before, otherwise I would've asked the same question :) I have never implemented it but it should not be very difficult I think.

Answer (score 1):

Given all the sheets other than the one you are leaving and the one you are going to will be hidden, then you can address directly just the sheet you are exiting with this `Workbook` level event (goes in `ThisWorkbok`)

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
Sh.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following event, placed in the Workbook code module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

Call _Your_Macro_Name_

End Sub
```

Replace `_Your_Macro_Name_` with the name of the subroutine that you want to execute.